# How to get video from s3 of first few minutes

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I am creating a web application using NodeJs where user can uploading a long video on s3 and I want to show only first 5 minutes of video to other users and i don't want to upload new trimmed video.
i have tried calculating bytes of first 5 minutes but it is not giving desired output

```
           
            const videoDuration = 105;
            const desiredDuration = 60;
            const outputBytes = (nVideoSize / videoDuration) * desiredDuration;
            const start = 0;
            const end = Math.floor(outputBytes);
            const headers = {
            'Content-Range': bytes ${start}-${end}/${Math.floor(outputBytes)},
            'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
            'Content-Length': Math.floor(outputBytes),
            'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
            };
            response = await axios.get(oFilmData.sLongFilmURL, {
            responseType: 'stream',
            });

            res.writeHead(206, headers);
            response.data.pipe(res);
```

nVideoSize is total bytes of full video

Here i am trying to get the bytes of first 60 seconds and tried to give video stream in response but i am not getting desired video in response.

if anybody have suggestion then please let me know
Thank you.

Comment: Video containers are complicated formats, you can't just extract arbitrary byte ranges from them and have the resulting results work.  One solution is to use [ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046930/how-to-cut-a-video-in-specific-start-end-time-in-ffmpeg-by-node-js) to parse and trim the content.

Comment: Thank you @AnonCoward for your reply, I have tried this solution and it works but I don't want to create a new file of the trimmed video i want the first few minutes and want to send that partial content from the original long video in response.

Does AWS s3 provide features like url based transformation as in Cloudinary?

Comment: Not really, no.  You could construct something like such a feature with [S3 Object Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/object-lambda/), but that would require quite a bit of work to get to a feature set as complete as what Cloudinary offers.